# Resolved C# Mysql Query (Select) return wrong result compare to Mysql Workbench

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I've got an little issue with SQL query for an MySQL db.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable.requests 
WHERE (myAccount= 'test') 
  AND MONTH(Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
  AND YEAR(Date) = YEAR(current_date()) 
  AND (State = 'Closed') 
group by Date;
```

This SQL return 3 rows in Workbench.

With y C# code the result is 16050 (!!)
What am I missing ?

'''

```
        MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = mySQLEngineObj.GetConnectionObject();
        int myRecordsCount = 0;

        if (mySqlConnection == null)
            return -1;
        else { 
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable.requests " +
                                    "WHERE ((myAccount= @account) " +
                                    "AND MONTH(requests.Date) = MONTH(NOW()) " +
                                    "AND YEAR(requests.Date) = YEAR(NOW()) ) " +
                                    "AND requests.State = @state " +
                                    "GROUP BY requests.Date";

         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", "Closed");
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", user.name);
         
         MySqlDataReader test = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (test.HasRows)
            {
                test.Read();

            }
        }
```

'''

Code test.GetInt32(0) return an wrong result.

Any idea?
Regards

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the columns you're querying rather than `*`.

Comment: Your query is wrong (incomplete GROUP BY). Only `Date` have definite value, all another columns will contain randomly selected values from all values in a group.

Comment: what is ```myTable.requests``` and ```requests.Date``` ?

Comment: @Beso If the query is executed without error then `myTable` is database name and `requests` is a table name in this database.

Comment: Why are the queries different? I'm not sure it's what is wrong, but 'CURRENT_DATE()' returns YYYY-MM-DD (string) or YYYYMMDD (numeric). NOW() on the other hand return 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS' (string) or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu (numeric).

MONTH() seems to be expecting a date....not sure if it can handle a date/time: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: @Akina there are three different approach ```myTable.requests``` , ```myAccount``` and ```requests.Date```. This is confusing.

Comment: @Beso What are another 2 approaches? except `myAccount` is local variable...

Comment: @Akina if you use ```myTable``` as schema name, you should use everyplace, like this: ```myTable.requests``` , ```myTable.requests.myAccount``` and ```myTable.requests.Date```

Comment: @Beso This is not correct. In MySQL at least. MySQL expands all objects names till their complete form during execution plan building, so it makes no sence does the database name is specified or not in any particular name. The only requirement is ambiguity absence.

Comment: Sorry I've made a wrong copy / paste :(

Here is the SQL query from MySQL Workbench which returns 3 rows:

`SELECT table.GID, table.Computer, table.Date FROM table WHERE (table.GID= 'test') AND MONTH(table.Date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(table.Date) = YEAR(current_date()) AND (State = 'Closed') group by table.Date;`

My records in column **table.date** are like : YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: `test.Read();` only reads one row, you need to loop it `while(test.Read()){...` (and then you don't need `if (test.HasRows)`) And you really really should not cache connection and command objects, dispose immediately with `using`

Comment: @Charlieface it is better with your `while` do you have an example of what you're meaning by the dispose with `using` ?

Comment: A `using` block will automatically dispose the object. Like this `using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString)) { // code that executes SQL }` and the same with `MySqlCommand`. Create it when you need it, dispose immediately after use

Comment: ok great thanks, everything work.